# Ensure direction of project is kept after opening source

Tags: agile, team-management, planning, software-development, process

I had an idea and started working on a web site which aims to be of societal value. I believe making it open-source would benefit the project. Doing this will be a turning point where I no longer have full influence on the project.

> It is amazing what you can accomplish if you do not care who gets the credit (HS Truman)

However, I don't want to see the project not reaching the goals of my vision because the direction of the project changes. Can I, and should I, set the project foundation "in stone"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about developing an idea for a product that you want to exploit,  rather than project management.

Comment: This question is not about project management within the scope defined by our Help Center.

Comment: Rewrote the q, it now has partly different content. lain9688's comment was relevant when it was posted.

Comment: The edits make this vaguely on-topic, but it's still a better fit for Programmers SE. You can set goals in a project charter, but you have limited means to control an open project, although you can always limit commit access to your canonical repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called **Crowdsourcing**. From Wikipedia:

> Crowdsourcing is the process of obtaining needed services, ideas, or content by soliciting contributions from a large group of people, and especially from an online community, rather than from traditional employees or suppliers.

There are tons of websites related to this.. Basically, you show what your idea is about and people that might find it interesting join your team to put it into practice.